# MySQL Starts with search

Tags: mysql

I have a list of zip codes in this format:

```
ZIP CODES
84038-4323
93434-4320
```

The user types it in like this: `84038`

I'm trying to figure out how to do something like this in MySQL

`SELECT * FROM locations WHERE ZipCode STARTSWITH '${userZip}'`

I need the first part of the zip code to match exactly.

I tried this

`SELECT * FROM locations WHERE ZipCode LIKE '${userZip}%'`

But it's returning extra data, it appears the `LIKE` command is not strict enough.

Comment: What are the actual SQL and the extra results?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `LIKE '${userZip}%'` it does exactly what you want. Can you show your table structure and also how are preparing the query?

Comment: @JorgeCampos You're right, I realized it had nothing to do with the LIKE command, it was the way I was importing the Zip Codes that was causing the problem, so the above code actually works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using `-` too in where condition. Something like below using REGEXP

`SELECT * FROM locations WHERE ZipCode REGEXP '^{userZip}-'`